# NHibernate refresh() of object in an object

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate

I have an WPF application with NHibernate for my database. Now I have a Customer object which holds an Address object.

**Customer class**

```
public class Customer:ObjectBase
{
    #region Variables
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private Address _address;
    private string _vat;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set 
        { 
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        { 
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public virtual Address Address
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_address == null)
                _address = new Address();
            return _address; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Vat
    {
        get
        {
            return _vat;
        }
        set
        {
            _vat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Vat");
        }
    }


    #endregion
}
```

**Address class**

```
public class Address:ObjectBase
{
    #region Variables
    private int _id;
    private string _street;
    private string _number;
    private string _city;
    private string _zip;
    private string _country;
    private Customer _customer;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Het unieke ID van een Address zoals deze in de database staat
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    /* ... all other properties ...*/
}
...
```

In my application I'm able to edit my Customer object. But I also have an undo button. When I click on that button it has to show the original data of that Customer without the changes. So I was thinking of executing the refresh function of the nhibernate session.

```
NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer);
```

But this refreshes all the properties except the values of the Address object in the Customer object. Is there a way to refresh the Address values?

I've tried

```
NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer.Address);
```

But this doesn't work...
Does anyone has an explanation or workaround to solve this issue?

---

**Edit: Possible solution**

When I execute it in the following order it gives me the whole default value of the object

```
NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer.Address);
NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer);
```

But I don't know why calling the refresh functions in that order does make it work. It's ok for me but any idea why it has to be in that order?

Comment: Can you supply the mapping file for your relationship?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes with NHibernate, I had to reset the session and clear the second cache to resolve the problem, and after I make a select to get my data:

```
public static void ClearCache(this ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    sessionFactory.EvictQueries();
    foreach (var collectionMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
             sessionFactory.EvictCollection(collectionMetadata.Key);
    foreach (var classMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
             sessionFactory.EvictEntity(classMetadata.Key);
}
```

Comment: I will also try your function. But I noticed (why I didn't tried it first, I don't know...) that when I execute: NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer.Address); first and after that I execute: NHibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(Customer); It does give me the default values. It's ok for me to work that way, but any idea why it works that way?

Comment: mmm no idea, it can be your mapping or anything else. That's what I don't like so much with NHibernate, I don't have enough control on the request and other stuff. But it's a really good FrameWork however.